# MySQL : Analyse Table Data by going to specific row and retrieve column value in the specific row

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have following dataset as a sample in a table.
Sorry, I am a newbie and do not know markdown syntax for table yet.

My data sample is below

```
## Data Table t ##
| idS_Data | S_id | S_dateTime     | value |
|:--------:|------|----------------|-------|
| 1        | 153  | 5/6/2014 7:00  | 1     |
| 2        | 153  | 5/6/2014 12:00 | 1     |
| 3        | 154  | 5/6/2014 14:00 | 1     |
| 4        | 154  | 5/6/2014 14:30 | 1     |
| 5        | 156  | 5/6/2014 15:30 | 1     |
| 6        | 156  | 5/6/2014 16:30 | 1     |
```

## Expected Result

I would like to get the following result

```
S_id |Time Difference
153  |05:00:00
154  |00:30:00
156  |01:00:00
```

## How ?

How Can this be achieved ?
My dataset is very big and I need to process the row sequentially.

## Pseudo code

My pesudo code is below:

1. Start at first row with S_id = First_row value in Col S_id
2. Retrive S_datetime as t1 for that row
3. Go to last row before where S_id changes its value (for example row 3 when S_id becomes 154 in my sample data)
4. retrieve datetime t2 = the Last Row for original S_id in first row . (row 2 in sample data)
5. Calculate timediff = t2-t1

Continue the above for the remaining rows from the row where next S-id starts (e.g. 154).

How can this be achieved ?

Any help kindly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S_id ,TIMEDIFF(MAX(S_dateTime),MIN(S_dateTime))
FROM t
GROUP BY S_id
```